# Javascript - Node.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am having some issues with Node.js.

I am trying to newsapi.org api to fetch top headline news.
When I hit 'http://localhost:8082/news/api/tech-crunch', it gets to '/news/api/:newsName' section inside the "tech-crunch" switch statement.

It does render the news in the first time but soon as it gets loaded, I am getting this "error: Can't set headers after they are sent".

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Below is my code for server.js:

```js
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

let __homeglobals = [];

app.use(cors({credentials:true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));
app.set("jsonp callback", true);

//fetch news by category
app.get('/news/api/:newsName', function(req, res) {
  const API_KEY = '6c78608600354f199f3f13ddb0d1e71a';

  let data = '';

  const techCrunchURL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=${API_KEY}`

  const businessInsiderURL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=business-insider&apiKey=${API_KEY}`

  let fetchedTechCrunchNews = {
    totalResults: '',
    articles: ''
  };

  switch(req.params.newsName) {
    case 'tech-crunch':
      request(techCrunchURL, function(err, response, html) {        
        
        let formattedData = JSON.parse(response.body);

        data = response.body;
    
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(data);
        
      });

    case 'business insider':
      request(businessInsiderURL, function(err, response, html) {
        let formattedData = JSON.parse(response.body);

        data = response.body;

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(data);
        
      });

    default:
      data = 'Please type in correct news source';
      break;
  }
})

var server = app.listen(8082, function () {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Comment: use return or break after each switch case

Comment: This happens when you try to send response after the response stream has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `break` after each `case`

```
switch(req.params.newsName) {
case 'tech-crunch':
  request(techCrunchURL, function(err, response, html) {        

    let formattedData = JSON.parse(response.body);

    data = response.body;

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);

  });
  break;

case 'business insider':
  request(businessInsiderURL, function(err, response, html) {
    let formattedData = JSON.parse(response.body);

    data = response.body;

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);

  });
  break;

default:
  data = 'Please type in correct news source';
  break;
}
```